# Java application user interface strange behavior

Tags: java, window

When running Java applications - both downloaded from the web and developed by myself, I am a software developer - sometimes a strange behavior would occur.

[image: Inlined screenshot]

As you can see, a part of the user interface has moved and overlapped with the rest of the window.

This problem mostly occurs when I do typing and opening new window, and although the interface is messed up, I can still use the application if I ignored the messed up interface - the buttons and text are still functioning.

For now, I simply close and reopen the application, and the problem will go away for a while, but sooner or later the same problem will happen again.

Its not a serious issue, but really annoying. please help me.

Other info:
My OS is windows 7 professional 64bit with service pack 1,
my java version is 1.7 built 1.7.0_17-b02.
Updating the Java doesn't seem to help.